# Angular2 package.json Dependencies?

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I'm new at Angular2 development. Looking at a few examples online, in the package.json file under the "dependencies", some examples have:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

While some examples have:

```
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
```

From what I have read, the @angular/.. is newer and used with the Release Candidates of Angular2.

Now some npm packages rely on "@angular/.." and some on "angular2". My question is can you have both in the package.json or will it cause issues? Also going forward with any new development I should ignore "angular2" and use "@angular/.." instead?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "RC" was released they changed the package name from angular2 to @angular.

> My question is can you have both in the package.json or will it cause
>   issues?

**If you mean to use the 'angular2' notation for newer version, the answer is NO. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense, as it would only work for versions prior to RC.**

> Also going forward with any new development I should ignore "angular2"
>   and use "@angular/.." instead?

**Yes, this is the standard and will probably be kept for the final release.**